# How change wordpress Date,Time Format

Tags: wordpress, datetime

Sorry friends, my English is not good.
I want to publish a post in WordPress instead of hitting the date normally. I want the date to be displayed like this, for example, 2 days ago (based on the time it was published), for example, if a post published 4 days ago shows the date 4 days ago, I don't want it like this: 12/02/2022.
I hope you understand what I mean.

I couldn't find anything on the internet

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.